# How should I represent the main method (java) using UML?

Tags: uml

I have three classes: Bridge, Main and Car.
I have no idea about how to include the main method in my UML representation.
Should I list all the attributes...as well as the main method?

The main method does:
- a bit of calculation 
- instantiate the other two classes

I would draw the Main, this way:

```
---------------------------
Main
---------------------------

---------------------------
+ main(String[] args): void

---------------------------
```

Is that correct?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your drawing is good, you just need to underline the main method to show that it is static. I think that you should model it since it shows that this class is one entry point to the system (there may be more).

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to include main method in your UML and also as I remember, you should put all the members and methods that are present in your class except the main method. Since the main method is somewhat a given already

Comment: do you mean that I should list every single attribute? ..My Main has one method that's the Main..sorry but I can't find an example of a Main

Comment: exampl.. public class Sample{

public int x,y;

public static void main()//somethingsomething{}


}

--------------------------
Main
---------------------------

---------------------------
+ x(int)
+ y(int)
---------------------------

Answer (score 0):

The main method should be drawn like this:

```
+ main(args: String[]): void
____________________________
```

Answer (score -1):

Main class has, by definition, no instance; Relationship like association, agregation and so on are used between objets, so the main class in a diagram is not very usefull.