# UML class diagrams main class

Tags: java, uml

In no examples online have I seen the main method included in class diagrams. If it should be there, how do I represent it? Is it just like any other method, preceded by + to denote public and underlined to show it's static? If main methods don't get included, why not?

Comment: There is no reason to down vote answers just if you don't like them.

Comment: Btw.: what is a "main method"? As per UML there is nothing like that. Do you mean the class initializer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I represent the main method (java) using UML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280301/how-should-i-represent-the-main-method-java-using-uml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `Main()` can be modeled as a public static operation, just like any other operation.

Whether or not you find it interesting to model depends on your viewpoint. If you wish to model the behavioral details and sequences of messages when running your application, then yes, it might be very useful.

If you are only interested in a structural "entity" class view, then the main class might not be that interesting.

Answer (score 4):

The main method is only use for init your application, it is not part of you application model. I think it should not be included in the UML diagram. It's the same as application servers you don't include the applicartion server classes in your Diagrams.

Comment: But the class that the main method is in should definitely get its own class diagram, right?

Comment: I would recommend you to use the class with main method only to init your application. In this case you don't need to include it into your diagram. But if the class that contains the main method is also part of the your application, the answer is yes you should do it.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll try and shift things around so my main is only there to initialise.